# Not receiving notification when using Azure hub notifications rest api

Tags: azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have registered my device to the hub and I am receiving the notification when sending the notification directly from azure portal.

But when using the rest api from postman, I am not receiving it although it returns me a 201 CREATED response.

I am not targeting any tags. I tried direct send, gcm native, apns native and could not receive any.